# Excluding a field from Serializer output in a Django REST API

Tags: api, rest, django-serializer

I'm a newbie in Django, learning now.
So i need help with Serializers.

What i received when creating user by POST request:

```
{
            "email": "testuser@test.com",
            "id": 3,
            "username": "test.user",
            "first_name": "Test",
            "last_name": "User",
            "is_subscribed": false
        },
```

According API requirements:
The field "is_subscribed" should not return in POST request, but only in GET request, so need to remove it.

User Serializer:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer,
                           ValidateUsernameSerializerMixin):
    """Сериализатор модели CustomUser."""

    is_subscribed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email',
                  'id',
                  'username',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'password',
                  'is_subscribed',
                  )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True},
                        'is_subscribed': {'read_only': True}}
    

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ...
 
    def create(self, validated_data):
        CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return self.to_representation(self)

    def get_is_subscribed(self, obj):
        user = self.context.get('request').user
        if not user.is_anonymous:
            return Follow.objects.filter(user=user, author=obj).exists()
        return False
```

I've tried to use def to_representation(self, instance), but with no luck.
What is the way to use it?

Comment: I guess you can remove this field from the views layer. Maybe you can do something like `request.data.pop("is_subscribed")` before passing the request data to the serializer. Could you share your views as well?